Excel - apply one cell to multiple searches
I'm not sure on formula to use here.
I need to search which cell data with data would apply for voluntary and involuntary.
So on 1 sheet I have all voluntary % involuntary options:

In another sheet I have employees with reason of leaving and I need to add in new column whether the reason applies for voluntary or involuntary

I didnt try much as I cannot find any answer.

So it's always a reason as listed, or can it be unlisted also?

=IF(ISNA(XMATCH(D2:D23,A2:A10)),B1,A1)

Use INDEX(AGGREGATE())
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$10)/(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$10=$E2),1))


Very nice Scott! Learnt to use AGGREGATE this way.

With XMATCH:

stack both lists and perform lookup

=LET(
    voluntary, TRIM(Sheet1!A2:A10),
    voluntary_rows, ROWS(voluntary),
    involuntary, TRIM(Sheet1!B2:B6),
    reason, TRIM(A2:A22),
    IFERROR(
        IF(
            XMATCH(reason, VSTACK(voluntary, involuntary)) < voluntary_rows,
            "Voluntary",
            "Involuntary"
        ),
        ""
    )
)


